# How write operation works in firebase RTDB, executes even after Cloud functions are timeout

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Since few months we are facing timeout in our many Cloud functions, when we read/write in firebase RTDB.

We noticed that when we read data from RTDB and function timeout, function execution is finished . But when we write data in RTDB and function timeout, write operation would happen after few mins even function is timeout. Don't know why and how this is happening. Is write operation add some where in a queue? How firebase RTDB Write operation work with firebase CF's.

Below adding code snippet for the reference.

```
exports.manager = functions.database.instance(instanceName11).ref('/A/sk').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    return managerHandler(snapshot, context, false);
});

function managerHandler(snapshot, context, onUpdate) {
    const skipData = snapshot.val();
    // if (printDebugLogs)
    console.log('skipData: ', skipData);
    // console.log('onUpdate ',onUpdate)
    if (skipData) {
        // const skip = skipData.split("_");
        const player = skipData;

        const mNodeRef = snapshot.ref.parent.once("value")
        const cardsRef = snapshot.ref.parent.parent.parent.child("P").child(player).child("c").once("value")

        return Promise.all([cardsRef, mNodeRef]).then(snapResults => {
            var cards = snapResults[0].val()
            const bid = snapResults[1].val()
            // if (printDebugLogs) 
            {
                console.log('bid : ', bid);
                console.log('cards: ', cards);
            }
            var d = bid.d;
            const p1Card = d != null ? d.i : null
            const p2Card = d != null ? d.j : null
            const p3Card = d != null ? d.k : null
            const p4Card = d != null ? d.l : null

            var bidValue;

            if (bid.u == "-") {
                bidValue = parseInt(getBidForPlayer(getCardsAsList(cards)));
                if (bidValue < 1) {
                    bidValue = 1;
                }

                var mergedUpdate = {};
                mergedUpdate['/sk'] = null;
                mergedUpdate['/z'] = 1;
                
                return snapshot.ref.parent.update(mergedUpdate, (error) => {
                    if (error) {
                        logError(error);
                    } else {
                        console.log("bidSkipManagerHandler ", 'Data saved successfully.');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**update operation happen even timeout**

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the write operation has already been sent to the server, and has just not been confirmed to the client yet by the time the function gets terminated.

Aside from that, although I don't think it's related to the question, I'd recommend using *either* promises *or* Firebase's classic callbacks, but not both. So that'd be:

```
return snapshot.ref.parent.update(mergedUpdate).then((error) => {
    if (error) {
        logError(error);
    } else {
        console.log("bidSkipManagerHandler ", 'Data saved successfully.');
    }
    return true;
});
```